# Odoo shop - Auto login thanks to POST URL

Tags: odoo

I am trying to redirect from a website to a user cart in Odoo (The cart has products inside).
The user is registered but not logged in. How to auto login thanks to POST URL?
I already tried something as

> ip/web/login?db=pos-s99-01&login=mail@gmail.com&password = blabla&redirect=shop

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you want to hard code your username & password in the url which is a very very bad way, you could use this endpoint ```/web/session/authenticate``` instead. this will take a json data then you could redirect